# How can my friend stream a game from my Xbox One to my RTMP server?

Tags: rtmp, xbox-one

My friend has just began streaming, but on his Xbox One. I use PC to stream my games and have never done it through Xbox One. Now he streams using the Twitch app. But i have this RTMP Server which i can use to stream his stream to Twitch with having some extra enhancements! How do i do this?

Comment: This should be on superuser, not stackoverflow.

Answer (score 0):

Setup transparent proxy for RTMP. kinda like [this](http://www.dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/Squid_Transparent_Proxy). A ddwrt router is probablly best, but any linux box should work.

```
#!/bin/sh
XBO=192.168.1.20
PROXY_IP=192.168.1.2    
RTMP_PORT=1935
LAN_IP=`nvram get lan_ipaddr`
LAN_NET=$LAN_IP/`nvram get lan_netmask`

iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i br0 -s $XBO -d $LAN_NET -p tcp --dport $RTMP_PORT -j ACCEPT
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i br0 -s ! $PROXY_IP -p tcp --dport $RTMP_PORT -j DNAT --to $PROXY_IP:$RTMP_PORT
iptables -t nat -I POSTROUTING -o br0 -s $LAN_NET -d $PROXY_IP -p tcp -j SNAT --to $LAN_IP
iptables -I FORWARD -i br0 -o br0 -s $LAN_NET -d $PROXY_IP -p tcp --dport $RTMP_PORT -j ACCEPT
```

Then configure nginx almost exactly like [this](https://www.vultr.com/docs/setup-nginx-rtmp-on-ubuntu-14-04). Modify the nginx config slightly (below) and started the broadcast on the ps4 this is the result

Just change the exec command to do whatever you want

```
rtmp {
server {
        listen 1935;
        chunk_size 4096;

        application app {
                live on;  
                record off;
                exec ffmpeg -i rtmp://localhost/app/$name -filter_complex "drawtext=fontfile=/usr/share/fonts/truetype/ttf-dejavu/DejaVuSans-Bold.ttf:text='m3u8':fontsize=50:fontcolor=white@0.8:x=100:y=100" -c:v libx264 -g 2 -profile:v main -b:v 800K -s 640x480 -f flv -c:a aac -ac 1 -strict -2 -b:a 56k rtmp://live.twitch.tv/app/$name;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: His Xbox One is at his house and the server is at mine? So how will this work? Which place do i set up the linux box/transparent proxy for RTMP?

Comment: It may work to put the the ip at his location. Or you can run an ssh tunnel.

Comment: So where do i put the transparent proxy

Comment: Please move this topic to super user. Stack overflow is for programming.

Comment: Moved @szatmary

https://superuser.com/questions/1011402/how-can-my-friend-stream-a-game-from-his-xbox-one-to-my-rtmp-server